# How to modify computed property output based on change\event of a button in VueJs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vue-storefront

I am adding pagination in a page , 
i have an array of products returning from computed property

```js
computed: {
    wishlistItems () {
      const wishlistItems = this.items
      const reversedItems = wishlistItems.map((item, index) => wishlistItems[wishlistItems.length - 1 - index])
      return reversedItems
    }
  },
```

i have change event here -

```html
<pagination class="my-20" :total="wishlistItems.length" @change="paginateProducts" :key="'pagination-'" />
```

& method

```js
methods: {
    paginateProducts (pageNumber) {
      this.mergeSearchOptions({
        append: false,
        route: this.$route,
        store: this.$store,
        current: (parseInt(pageNumber) - 1) * this.pagination.perPage
      })
```

Is their any way i can alter the output of that computed property based on change event function/parameter ?

Answers appreciated

Comment: Alter in what way?

Comment: like computed property return array of  10 items i have to change output on change button to return only 5 items